# Indicators & wiper failure after running for a while

Tags: mercedes-benz, windshield-wipers, indicators

I have a Mercedes 1995 C180 which is giving me a headache. The problem is a recent one, and is basically that the indicators and wipers sometimes fail. The strange thing is that the problem only surfaces when I've been driving the car (for 20mins+), shut it down and then tried to start it again (for instance going to the supermarket). And the likeliness of this happening depends on for how long I've been driving the car. Both the indicators and wipers would fail. Sometimes the wipers would kick in even without being manually triggered (there's no rain sensor on the car). It'd take a few tries to switch them off.

Any thought appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

I suspect that the indicator relay is faulty, this relay is also responsible for the wiper and heating of the rear window.
In the fuse box in the engine department you can find the relay, it should look like this:[image]

Comment: I've tried taking it to a shop, but everything always works when I get there. Do you know how much a relay like that costs? Could I replace it with a generic relay?

Comment: The part number SHOULD(!) be 2028204626, the cost online should by at around 60$. This is a specialized part, just some generic relay wont work. I guess it should be viable to do this yourself. From my understanding this relay is a frequent troublemaker

Comment: I see. I've heard that the "combination relay" could also be problematic. Are they the same relay?

Comment: it is combination relay, yes

Comment: Thanks! Do you know if there's a good way to test my current relay?

Comment: Unfortunately not, since the defect is only sporadic..
I only can recommend you to buy one where you can give it back, in case the fault persists.

Comment: I see. I'll pull it out and take a look then. Should I pull it out with just brute force? Will I need to disconnect the battery before pulling it out?

Comment: Brute force is always bad. Normally a relay sits a bit stiff so it will need a bit of force, but you need to "feel" it when there is too much force. If you damage the relay carrier it will be costly. Disconnecting the battery before repairs on the electronics is always a good idea. In your case i also recommend it.